# Image Transformation (strong wind) c/c++

Tags: c++, c, image, transformation, warp

I want to manipulate a Image like this:
http://cdn.jolie.de/bilder/frisuren-fuer-eckige-gesichter-400x500-641657.jpg

after the manipulation it should have a effect like this:
http://old.likeyou.com/artistsbios/gfx.php?id=9025

like strong wind is blowing in your face.

Did you have any hints/ideas how i can achieve this ?
For Face-detection is use OpenCV.

Comment: upper linked is dead

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add some anchor points wich are placed on certain edges of the face. when done you want to "warp" these anchor points to 1 direction (not to close else it will get weird) then toy around with some of the properties till you produce what you like.

2nd method:

Make a grid around the face wich you can warp the more grid the more detail although this will never be as pin point exact as anchor points.